# Define variable b of the same type as variable a

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, traits

Is it possible to declare a variable `var_b` of the same type as another variable, `var_a`?

For example:

```
template <class T>
void foo(T t) {

   auto var_a = bar(t);
   //make var_b of the same type as var_a

}


F_1 bar(T_1 t) {

}

F_2 bar(T_2 t) {

}
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Sure, use `decltype`:

```
auto var_a = bar(t);
decltype(var_a) b;
```

You can add cv-qualifiers and references to `decltype` specifiers as if it were any other type:

```
const decltype(var_a)* b;
```

Comment: it may be worth mentioning that decltype() gives you the *exact* type. in this example, if var_a is a reference, b won't be default constructible and will fail to compile. Clearly, this can be the case for any user defined type too.

Comment: You can get around the reference issue with [`std::remove_reference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference): `std::remove_reference<decltype(var_a)>::type b;`

Answer (score 13):

Despite the nice answer of @TartanLlama, this is another way one can use `decltype` to name actually the given type:

```
int f() { return 42; }

void g() {
    // Give the type a name...
    using my_type = decltype(f());
    // ... then use it as already showed up
    my_type var_a = f();
    my_type var_b = var_a;
    const my_type &var_c = var_b;
}

int main() { g(); }
```

Maybe it's worth to mention it for the sake of completeness.

note: the argument of `decltype` is not evaluated, `f` is not called.

Answer (score 6):

In ancient times before c++11 arrived people dealt with it using pure templates.

```
template <class Bar>
void foo_impl(Bar var_a) {
   Bar var_b; //var_b is of the same type as var_a
}

template <class T>
void foo(T t) {
   foo_impl(bar(t));
}


F_1 bar(T_1 t) {

}

F_2 bar(T_2 t) {

}
```

Comment: Personally, I'd say this answer is good for maintaining legacy code, or for writing new code designed to integrate with a code base from pre-C++11, but `decltype` would be more useful for projects developed for C++11 or later.

Comment: Legacy code still exists so I'd say this is still relevant. Especially when most compilers still aren't entirely C++11 compliant (about 99%, but that 1% still matters). Besides which the OP has already demonstrated that they're using templates already, and I'd say this solution could be used in conjunction with `decltype`, it's not as if the two are mutually exclusive.