# How to determine a return type of a template?

Tags: c++

I've got the following function:

```
template<class F>
struct c_style_callback_t {
  F f;
  template<class...Args>
  static void(*get_callback())(Args..., void*) {
    return [](Args...args, void* fptr)->void {
      (*static_cast<F*>(fptr))(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    };
  }
  void* get_pvoid() {
    return std::addressof(f);
  }
};

template<class F>
c_style_callback_t< std::decay_t<F> >
c_style_callback( F&& f ) { return {std::forward<F>(f)}; }
```

I've been using it like:

```
auto task = c_style_callback(
  [=] (Foo *foo, char *bar) { ... }
);
```

But now I want to store `task` in a `vector<???>`. What type needs to be used here?

What I have tried is to change the `auto` to `int` so that the compiler printed the error about not being able to convert things. I copy-pasted the type from there replacing the `int` but it didn't work.

Error on purpose to see what the compiler expects as type:

```
error: cannot convert 'c_style_callback_t<SomeClass::subscribe(const string&, std::function<void(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&)>, QoS)::<lambda(Foo*, char*)> >' to 'int' in initialization
```

Replaced `auto`:

```
c_style_callback_t<SomeClass::subscribe(const string&, std::function<void(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&)>, QoS)::<lambda(Foo*, char*)> > task2 = c_style_callback(
  [=] (Foo *foo, char *bar) { }
);
```

New error:

```
error: template argument 1 is invalid
 c_style_callback_t<SomeClass::subscribe(const string&, std::function<void(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&)>, QoS)::<lambda(Foo*, char*)> > task2 = c_style_callback(
 error: cannot convert 'c_style_callback_t<SomeClass::subscribe(const string&, std::function<void(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&)>, QoS)::<lambda(Foo*, char*)> >' to 'int' in initialization
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Define variable b of the same type as variable a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37393546/define-variable-b-of-the-same-type-as-variable-a)

Comment: What exactly do you want stored in the vector? Functions with the same definitions(calling parameter types and return type) ? Or diffrent types of function definitions?

Comment: Same type of function definitions.

Comment: How about declaring a `static vector<decltype(task)> vec; vec.push_back(task);` right after `task`?

Comment: The vector needs to be global, can't declare it after `task`.

Comment: Why does it have to be global?

Comment: Because that would contain references to locally created variables (`auto task = c_style_callback(...);`) in order to prevent them from getting destroyed.

Comment: `static` lifetime is from first call until end of program.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180112/discussion-between-haxpanel-and-robert-andrzejuk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand you need to know the type of your c_style_callback in order to store any instance of c_style_callback into a vector.

To have an idea of the type that task has you can do

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
template<class F>
struct c_style_callback_t {
    F f;
    template<class...Args>
    static void(*get_callback())(Args..., void*) {
        return [](Args...args, void* fptr)->void {
            (*static_cast<F*>(fptr))(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        };
    }
    void* get_pvoid() {
        return std::addressof(f);
    }
};

template<class F>
c_style_callback_t< std::decay_t<F> >
c_style_callback(F&& f) { return { std::forward<F>(f) }; }
int main()
{
    auto task = c_style_callback(
        [=](double *foo, char *bar) {  }
    );
    std::cout << typeid(decltype(task)).name() << std::endl;

    std::vector<decltype(task)> v;

    v.push_back(task);
    return 0;
}
```

This code returns (on Visual Studio 2017)

```
struct c_style_callback_t<class <lambda_f2990127907fab7e430587a3832f9637> >
```

And there you see problem begins. Lambda expression have unique types see [Can the 'type' of a lambda expression be expressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867276/can-the-type-of-a-lambda-expression-be-expressed) .

Answer (score 0):

This requires C++14.

Create a function that returns an auto of the callback function.

```
auto create_callback(/**/)
{
    return c_style_callback([=](Foo* foo, char* bar) { //...
    });
}
```

Then a vector can be created of the decltype of the function:

```
std::vector< decltype(create_callback()) > vec;
```

Then it is possible to do:

```
auto task = create_callback();
vec.emplace_back(task);
```